# main.c: undefined reference to `test1'

Tags: c

My code as below:

header.h

```
typedef struct {
 int AA;
 char BB[48];
} test;
static int siz_test=sizeof(test);
```

main.c

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
 int k;
 extern test *test1;
 k=test1->AA;
 return k;
}
```

But when build program, error prompted as below:
main.c: undefined reference to `test1'
How can I fix this issue, thanks.

Comment: `extern test *test1;` - so where is `test1`?

Comment: So... where's `test1` actually *defined* ? All you've done in `main` is declare that it exists somewhere. It has to still *be* somewhere.

Comment: Try `extern test *test1 = NULL;` - so the compiler knows that, even though you have the `extern` qualifier, you are defining it locally.

Comment: @AdrianMole Although then the OP will attempt to dereference a null pointer, which leads to other problems. IMO the OP needs to take a couple of steps back, and refresh some of the basics of C.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed - I misread the following line of code. Of course, `test1` needs to be assigned a proper value at some point.

Comment: Why the `extern`?  What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Maybe this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

```
extern test *test1;
```

is telling the compiler  that `test1` exists somewhere.

On the other hand, you did not provide `test1`.

You should add something like `test1.c`:

```
#include "header.h"

test buffer;
test* test1 = &buffer;
```

and add this for linking.